# Accessing a object list outside of a nested foreach loop

Tags: c#

```
foreach (var folder in pathList)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
    foreach (var file in di.GetFiles())

    {
        fileinfoList.Add(new FileInfo() 
        {
            partNumber = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Convert.ToString(file)),
            fileType = Path.GetExtension(Convert.ToString(file)),
            lastDate = file.LastWriteTime,
            released = 1,
            checkedBy = null,
            fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(Convert.ToString(folder)),
        } );
    }        
}
```

I'm pretty new to programming and I've been stuck on this for a while.

I need to compare the partNumber (from fileInfoList) property to a list of strings, the problem is, I can't seem to access partNumber outside the foreach scope, even though fileInfoList isn't declared in the loop.Can someone help me out?
The code for i'm trying to access the property is(and it obviously doesn't work):

```
var listDbVsServer = dbList.Except(fileinfoList.partNumber).toList() ;
```

Comment: Please share the code where you try and access `partNumber`. [edit] your question and add this code

Comment: Your first post beeing edited by Jon Skeet, you lucky one ;-)

Comment: What @canton7 is asking is a [mcve]

Comment: A `List<T>` doesn't have a `partNumber` property. Do you want the partnumber of each element? Then you probably want `dbList.Except(fileinfoList.Select( f => f.partNumber))`

Comment: `fileinfoList` is a list of `FileInfo` objects. Each of the objects inside the list has a `partNumber` property, but the list itself does not (and if it did, what would it contain? The `partNumber` of the first item in the list? The last item in the list?).

Comment: The .Select method worked, thanks guys!